# Calendar to DataGrid

Tags: c#, .net, sql, datagrid, calendar

I really can't seem to nail down what I need to accomplish my task. I have a DataGrid in asp.net in VS2010 this displays data from a SQL database , in one of these fields is a "StartDate".

Also I have a simple Calendar running . What I would like is to be able to update my DataGrid by passing it the selected date and using that as the "StartDate" to call a selection on the DataGrid , so only records with that start date will appear.

I have looked on-line but the examples are very old or are a bit confusing .

If anyone can layout the steps (if possible sample code) involved to achieve this i would be grateful or any resources or examples you have come across though I have searched for a while, hence the post!.

Thanks.

What i have currently is

```
   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {

            Calendar1.VisibleDate = DateTime.Today;
            strConn = @"Data Source=PC88;Initial Catalog=Bookings;Integrated Security=True";    
            mycn = new SqlConnection(strConn);
            myda = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * FROM Bookings", mycn);
            myda.Fill(ds, "Table");
        }
        else 
        {
           // CalendarChange();
            Calendar1.VisibleDate = DateTime.Today;
            strConn = @"Data Source=PC88;Initial Catalog=Bookings;Integrated Security=True";    
            mycn = new SqlConnection(strConn);
            myda = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * FROM Bookings", mycn);
            myda.Fill(ds, "Table");

        }

    }

    protected void CalendarDRender(object sender, System.Web.UI.WebControls.DayRenderEventArgs e)
    {
        // If the month is CurrentMonth
        if (!e.Day.IsOtherMonth)
        {
            foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
            {
                if ((dr["Start"].ToString() != DBNull.Value.ToString()))
                {
                    DateTime dtEvent = (DateTime)dr["Start"];
                    if (dtEvent.Equals(e.Day.Date))
                    {
                        e.Cell.BackColor = Color.PaleVioletRed;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        //If the month is not CurrentMonth then hide the Dates
        else
        {
        e.Cell.Text = "";
        }
        }


        private void Calendar1_SelectionChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
        myda = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * from Bookings where Start ='" + Calendar1.SelectedDate.ToString() + "'", mycn);
        dsSelDate = new DataSet();
        myda.Fill(dsSelDate, "AllTables");
        if (dsSelDate.Tables[0].Rows.Count == 0 )
        {
        GridView1.Visible = false;
        }
        else
        {
        GridView1.Visible = true;
        GridView1.DataSource = dsSelDate;
        GridView1.DataBind (); 
        }
      } 
    }
```

What am i doing wrong?.

EDIT__

Finally it works , Here is my code if anyone has similar issue/requirement.

```
   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {

                Calendar1.VisibleDate = DateTime.Today;
                strConn = @"Data Source=BBC-PC-S054683;Initial Catalog=Bookings;Integrated Security=True";
                mycn = new SqlConnection(strConn);
                myda = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * FROM Bookings", mycn);
                myda.Fill(ds, "Table");

            }
            else
            { // CalendarChange();
                Calendar1.VisibleDate = DateTime.Today;
                strConn = @"Data Source=PC-Name;Initial Catalog=Bookings;Integrated Security=True";
                mycn = new SqlConnection(strConn);
                myda = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * FROM Bookings", mycn);
                myda.Fill(ds, "Table");

            }

            BindGrid();
        }
    }
    private DataTable GetRecords()
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(strConnection);
        conn.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.Connection = conn;
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.CommandText = "Select * from Bookings";
        SqlDataAdapter dAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
        dAdapter.SelectCommand = cmd;
        DataSet objDs = new DataSet();
        dAdapter.Fill(objDs);
        return objDs.Tables[0];


    }

    public void Calendar1_SelectionChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {

        String Date = Calendar1.SelectedDate.ToLongDateString();
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnection);//put connection string here
        SqlCommand objCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Bookings where Date = '" + Date + "'", con);//let MyTable be a database table
        con.Open();
        SqlDataReader dr = objCommand.ExecuteReader(); 

        GridView.DataSource = dr;
        GridView.DataBind();



                    }
```

Comment: There's no need to put an isPostBack inside an isPostBack. Both conditions will always have the same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to filter your `DataGridView`.

```
try
{
    myDataSet = new DataSet();
    myDataSet.CaseSensitive = true;

    DataAdapter.SelectCommand.Connection = myConnection;
    DataAdapter.TableMappings.Clear();
    DataAdapter.TableMappings.Add("Table", "TableName");
    DataAdapter.Fill(myDataSet);

    myDataView = new DataView(myDataSet.Tables["TableName"], "TIMESTAMP >= '" + 
    Convert.ToDateTime(fromDate) + "' AND TIMESTAMP <= '" + 
    Convert.ToDateTime(toDate) + "'", "TIMESTAMP", DataViewRowState.CurrentRows);

    dgv.DataSource = myDataView;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```

`TIMESTAMP` is a column in my DataGridView. 
**Note: This is just a code snippet!**